# Why と言っていました and not と言いました

Tags: grammar

My textbook I studied from many months ago stated that to quote what somebody said, you have to use と言っていました.  I was wondering why that form is used and not と言いました。 Is there any specific reason for it?

Comment: Have you ever said, "I was saying" and not "I said"?

Comment: Too good question to answer.

Comment: I usually use said, not was saying. 'Was saying' sounds more like something an American would say.

Comment: @kiss-o-matic "Said" vs "Was saying" in English has very little (like nothing) to do with this, even though that is often used for an answer to this question on internet.  Truth is it is much more complicated.  Otherwise, people would not keep asking this question in the first place.

Comment: @l'électeur Are you saying that people repeating the same question over time is generally a valid reason to assume that the answers already given are wrong?

Comment: @l'électeur how is this complicated in the least?  My example isn't a 1:1 correlation for sure, but how could anyone draw a conclusion (like any conclusion) w/o context?